# C++ Edit Box Text Change

Tags: c++, windows

Is their any cases in C++ Like these
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))

That happen when you change the text of a edit Box, I need to call a function when i change in edit box and store the value of the edit box into a Integer.

Comment: In most cases you don't need to worry about when the value changes. If you have a button (e.g. OK) that the user needs to press before anything is done, you can call `GetWindowText()`/`GetDlgItemInt()` or similar in the handler for the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You receive an [EN_CHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761676%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) notification for the editbox whose content has changed.